# Tensorflow runs out of memory for CPU before GPU?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to determine how big a model I can run on my CPU vs GPU. Using the code below as a template, I started with a small network, and increased the parameters until failure. To my surprise, the first failure was with the exact code below with an out of memory error for the CPU.

My GPU has 12GB of RAM. My CPU has 128GB of RAM. Why would the CPU run out of memory before the GPU? How do I get tensorflow to use more memory with the CPU?

```
import time

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy      as np

from tensorflow import keras

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

X_train_scaled  = X_train/ 255
X_test_scaled   = X_test / 255
y_train_encoded = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes = 10, dtype = 'float32')
y_test_encoded  = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test,  num_classes = 10, dtype = 'float32')

def get_model():
  model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(32,32,3)),
    keras.layers.Dense(20000, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(20000, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='sigmoid')
  ])
  model.compile(optimizer='SGD',
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model

with tf.device('/GPU:0'):
  model_gpu = get_model()
  t0 = time.time()
  model_gpu.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train_encoded, epochs = 1)
  t1 = time.time()
  print('GPU: ', t1 - t0)

with tf.device('/CPU:0'):
  model_cpu = get_model()
  t0 = time.time()
  model_cpu.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train_encoded, epochs = 1)
  t1 = time.time()
  print('CPU: ', t1 - t0)
```

When I run the code above, I get the following output.

```
2022-03-15 02:04:41.968970: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:925] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:0b:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2022-03-15 02:04:41.972553: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:925] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:0b:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2022-03-15 02:04:41.972749: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:925] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:0b:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2022-03-15 02:04:41.973141: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-03-15 02:04:41.975086: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:925] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:0b:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2022-03-15 02:04:41.975318: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:925] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:0b:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2022-03-15 02:04:41.975535: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:925] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:0b:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2022-03-15 02:04:42.332615: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:925] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:0b:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2022-03-15 02:04:42.332868: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:925] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:0b:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2022-03-15 02:04:42.332901: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1609] Could not identify NUMA node of platform GPU id 0, defaulting to 0.  Your kernel may not have been built with NUMA support.
2022-03-15 02:04:42.333147: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:925] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:0b:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2022-03-15 02:04:42.333209: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1525] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 9396 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:0b:00.0, compute capability: 8.6
2022-03-15 02:04:44.056461: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1774] TensorFloat-32 will be used for the matrix multiplication. This will only be logged once.
1563/1563 [==============================] - 36s 23ms/step - loss: 1.7839 - accuracy: 0.3684
GPU:  36.7231342792511
2022-03-15 02:05:22.016145: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:802] failed to alloc 2147483648 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2022-03-15 02:05:22.016190: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/device/device_host_allocator.h:46] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 2147483648
2022-03-15 02:05:22.786090: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:802] failed to alloc 1932735232 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2022-03-15 02:05:22.786147: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/device/device_host_allocator.h:46] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 1932735232
2022-03-15 02:05:23.549123: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:802] failed to alloc 1739461632 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2022-03-15 02:05:23.549172: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/device/device_host_allocator.h:46] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 1739461632
2022-03-15 02:05:24.478277: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:802] failed to alloc 2147483648 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2022-03-15 02:05:24.478325: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/device/device_host_allocator.h:46] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 2147483648
2022-03-15 02:05:35.315236: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:802] failed to alloc 2147483648 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2022-03-15 02:05:35.315301: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/device/device_host_allocator.h:46] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 2147483648
2022-03-15 02:05:36.087838: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:802] failed to alloc 2147483648 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2022-03-15 02:05:36.087884: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/device/device_host_allocator.h:46] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 2147483648
2022-03-15 02:05:36.087902: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:462] Allocator (gpu_host_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 1.49GiB (rounded to 1600000000)requested by op SGD/SGD/update_2/ResourceApplyGradientDescent
If the cause is memory fragmentation maybe the environment variable 'TF_GPU_ALLOCATOR=cuda_malloc_async' will improve the situation. 
Current allocation summary follows.
Current allocation summary follows.
2022-03-15 02:05:36.087925: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1010] BFCAllocator dump for gpu_host_bfc
2022-03-15 02:05:36.087942: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (256):  Total Chunks: 5, Chunks in use: 5. 1.2KiB allocated for chunks. 1.2KiB in use in bin. 28B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-03-15 02:05:36.087949: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (512):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-03-15 02:05:36.087954: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (1024):         Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-03-15 02:05:36.087959: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (2048):         Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-03-15 02:05:36.087964: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (4096):         Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-03-15 02:05:36.087968: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (8192):         Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-03-15 02:05:36.087972: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (16384):        Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-03-15 02:05:36.087977: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (32768):        Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-03-15 02:05:36.087981: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (65536):        Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-03-15 02:05:36.087985: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (131072):       Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-03-15 02:05:36.087990: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (262144):       Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-03-15 02:05:36.087995: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (524288):       Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 1. 781.2KiB allocated for chunks. 781.2KiB in use in bin. 781.2KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2022-03-15 02:05:36.088001: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (1048576):      Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 0. 1.24MiB allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-03-15 02:05:36.088005: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (2097152):      Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-03-15 02:05:36.088009: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (4194304):      Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-03-15 02:05:36.088014: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (8388608):      Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-03-15 02:05:36.088018: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (16777216):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-03-15 02:05:36.088023: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (33554432):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-03-15 02:05:36.088028: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (67108864):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-03-15 02:05:36.088033: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (134217728):    Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-03-15 02:05:36.088037: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1017] Bin (268435456):    Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-03-15 02:05:36.088041: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1033] Bin for 1.49GiB was 256.00MiB, Chunk State: 
2022-03-15 02:05:36.088046: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Next region of size 2097152
2022-03-15 02:05:36.088052: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] InUse at 303850000 of size 256 next 1
2022-03-15 02:05:36.088057: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] InUse at 303850100 of size 256 next 2
2022-03-15 02:05:36.088060: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] InUse at 303850200 of size 256 next 3
2022-03-15 02:05:36.088063: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] InUse at 303850300 of size 256 next 4
2022-03-15 02:05:36.088067: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] InUse at 303850400 of size 256 next 5
2022-03-15 02:05:36.088071: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] InUse at 303850500 of size 800000 next 6
2022-03-15 02:05:36.088074: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] Free  at 303913a00 of size 1295872 next 18446744073709551615
2022-03-15 02:05:36.088079: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1071]      Summary of in-use Chunks by size: 
2022-03-15 02:05:36.088083: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1074] 5 Chunks of size 256 totalling 1.2KiB
2022-03-15 02:05:36.088087: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1074] 1 Chunks of size 800000 totalling 781.2KiB
2022-03-15 02:05:36.088091: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1078] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 782.5KiB
2022-03-15 02:05:36.088095: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1080] total_region_allocated_bytes_: 2097152 memory_limit_: 68719476736 available bytes: 68717379584 curr_region_allocation_bytes_: 2147483648
2022-03-15 02:05:36.088103: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1086] Stats: 
Limit:                     68719476736
InUse:                          801280
MaxInUse:                       801280
NumAllocs:                        6261
MaxAllocSize:                   800000
Reserved:                            0
PeakReserved:                        0
LargestFreeBlock:                    0

2022-03-15 02:05:36.088110: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:474] ***************************************_____________________________________________________________
2022-03-15 02:05:36.088143: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1745] OP_REQUIRES failed at training_ops.cc:973 : RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[20000,20000] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 by allocator gpu_host_bfc
```

Comment: As a memory test, I tried "memSoak = bytearray(30 * 2 ** 30)". I saw the expected 30GB of memory allocated.

Answer (score 1):

I think putting 20000 neurons in hidden layers is the problem here. You can lower the number of neurons in hidden layers to see the difference. I have put 128 and 64 neurons to resolve the issue in CPU mode.

```
def get_model():
  model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(32,32,3)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='sigmoid')
  ])
  model.compile(optimizer='SGD',
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model
```

Comment: @Tensorflow_Support:
This does not address the questions. Specifically, this answer does not explain why the GPU with less RAM than the CPU can run this model but the CPU runs out of memory. The point of putting 20000 neurons in hidden layers is to find the limits of what can be done on the CPU vs GPU. Putting 20000 neurons in hidden layers is the point, not the problem.

Comment: Got your point . Your question was about how a 12GB GPU RAM is more efficient than 128 GB CPU RAM. will update on it .Thanks!

Comment: Thanks; I appreciate you taking another look!

Comment: It's about how the data is being processed . A 12GB GPU has more no of cores than 128 GB CPU RAM and  efficient parallel distribution , load distribution , memory management. GPU's are more preferred than CPUs in deep learning because of those factors.

Comment: Would you please point me to a resource that explains how my problem can be explained by CPU vs GPU processing differences involving: number of cores, parallel distribution, load distribution, and memory management? I would like to understand exactly how any of the factors you mentioned lead to the problem I am having.

Comment: Sure. Putting some threads for reference.          
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-cpu-and-gpu/           https://www.javatpoint.com/gpu-vs-cpu

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to post an answer and comments. So far, none of what you have posted explains the behavior I am having.